# how can I prevent wget to filter BEFORE downloading files?

Tags: wget

When I try to use the wget `--accept` option, it actually downloads the
files and then delete them if they don't match the pattern. It seems to me it
should just not follow URLs matching the pattern in the first place. Is there
a way to enable this behavior?

Here's a sample command, in which I try to download all the files linked from a particular URL but only those matching a couple patterns:

```
wget \
  --directory-prefix=/Users/kueda/tmp \
  --recursive \
  --accept="*Plates.shtml,*fast.php,gif,png,css,js" \
  "http://example.com/foo.php?key=value"
```

And I get output like

```
--2014-07-21 18:06:05--  http://example.com/huh.html
Reusing existing connection to example.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6247 (6.1K) [text/html]
Saving to: `/Users/kueda/tmp/example.com/huh.html'

100%[=====================================>] 6,247       --.-K/s   in 0.02s   

2014-07-21 18:06:05 (304 KB/s) - `/Users/kueda/tmp/example.com/huh.html' saved [6247/6247]

Removing /Users/kueda/tmp/example.com/huh.html since it should be rejected.
```

I've tried `httrack` and it seems to have the same behavior. I'm guessing I'm missing an option b/c this seems absurd. FWIW I'm using GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on darwin11.2.0.

Comment: From [the wget man page](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/wget/wget_16.html#IDX77): "Note that these two options do not affect the downloading of HTML files; Wget must load all the HTMLs to know where to go at all--recursive retrieval would make no sense otherwise."

Comment: Ok, I guess it was a dumb question then. Related follow-up: how do you prevent it from downloading associated media referenced in HTML files that will be filtered out?

Comment: I don't know if you can. It's not really that dumb of a question, I can see why you'd want this behaviour. Can't really help though. You may be better off asking on superuser or askubuntu.